# Google Cloud: get current billing balance using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

My Google Cloud account contains many projects and servers, but only one Billing Account. So I'm writing a script to calculate my balance. I would like to export to BigQuery. My script:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service.json'
PROJECT_ID = 'poject'
DATA_SET = 'dataset'
TABLE_NAME = 'gcp_billing_export_v1_008DE2_378957_642BE6'

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE

client = bigquery.Client()

QUERY = ("SELECT SUM(cost) AS cost FROM `" + PROJECT_ID + "." + DATA_SET + "." + TABLE_NAME + "`" +
         " WHERE cost > 0")

query_job = client.query(QUERY)
rows = query_job.result()

for row in rows:
    print("Daily Cost:", row.cost)
```

It shows some information about all my projects and current costs. Now it should watch my balance so that if I spend over 200 USD, it will automatically charge from my bank card.

Which API method or library should I use?

Comment: You want to use [cloudbilling.projects.updateBillingInfo] API (https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateBillingInfo) to update the `billingAccountName` in individual projects when your billing costs shoots about 200 USD

Answer (score 0):

User Oluwafemi Sule mentioned "You want to use [cloudbilling.projects.updateBillingInfo] API ([cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/projects/…](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateBillingInfo)) to update the billingAccountName in individual projects when your billing costs shoots about 200 USD"